# Object type and boxing

Tags: c#, object, boxing

MSDN says that

> The object data type is the type to
>   and from which objects are boxed.

I thought only value types are boxed? Now I am bit confused. So when I assign reference type variable to object variable, its boxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only value types are boxed.

So, to be accurate the sentence should be:

"The `object` data type is the type to and from which *values* are boxed."

Answer (score 2):

It just states that `System.Object` is the type used when any object is boxed.

In other words, when a value type is boxed, it is boxed within `System.Object` type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes only value types are boxed. Boxing a value type packages it inside an instance of the Object reference type. What this statement says is that it is System.Object which is used to box/unbox value types to and from.

Answer (score 0):

Boxing is only done on value types. I'm wondering though why MSDN doesn't state it more precisely.